# It there any way to access RabbitMQ via HTTP POST request?

Tags: http, post, queue, rabbitmq, haproxy

I'm trying to figure out is it possible to access Rabbitmq with plain url?

For example:

```
+----------+                                       +--------+
| Producer |        ----------------------->       | Rabbit |
+----------+                                       +--------+

http://<rabbitmq-server>:5672?vhost="myvhost"&queue="myqueue"&message="foo"
```

If so, can you give me some example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, look at HTTP API, link at the bottom of the management interface page, or here: https://cdn.rawgit.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-management/rabbitmq_v3_6_12/priv/www/api/index.html

Comment: Note what that document says about the API route that allows you to post messages: "Please note that the publish / get paths in the HTTP API are intended for injecting test messages, diagnostics etc - they do not implement reliable delivery and so should be treated as a sysadmin's tool rather than a general API for messaging."

Comment: Hi  @tobych , is there any other way to achieve this?  As we want to use something like this in production.